# Serilog usage on a controller and class model

Tags: serilog

First warning, new both to C# and serilog, so excuse any bad wording or construct, here to learn.

I'm developing a REST API that will expose a few methods wanted to use a better log than just writing to a file so after a few reading here and there decide to give a go on serilog.

I can make it work and write simple log files with no problem, but didn't found a way to write to the same log file from both the controllers and the class models.

I can define 2 logs and write to one or the other, but would like to make it simpler and just have one log.

```
//Program.cs
//SeriLog Init
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .CreateLogger();

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    //.ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
    .WriteTo.File("../logs/all-.logs", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .CreateLogger();

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);
```

```
//Controler
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class WorkspaceController : ControllerBase
    {
        // logger instance injected to the Controller’s constructor
        private readonly ILogger<WorkspaceController> _logger;
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        public WorkspaceController(ILogger<WorkspaceController> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _config = configuration;
        }

        List<workspace> workspaces = new List<workspace> { };

        // GET: <WorkspaceController>
        [HttpGet()]
        public List<workspace> Get(string Custom1, string Custom2)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug("Inside GetWorkspace endpoint")
}
```

```
namespace WorkspaceCreatorAPI.Models
{
    public interface IAuthenticate
    {
        Session PasswordGrant(string serverUrl, string userName, string password, string clientId, string clientSecret, Enums.AuthenticationScope scope);
    }
    public class AuthenticationResponse
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("access_token")]
        public string? XAuthToken { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("token_type")]
        public string? TokenType { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("scope")]
        public string? Scope { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("refresh_token")]
        public string? RefreshToken { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("expires_in")]
        public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }

    }
    public class Authenticate : IAuthenticate
    {
         public Session PasswordGrant(string serverUrl, string userName, string password, string clientId, string clientSecret, Enums.AuthenticationScope scope)
        {
            var session = new Session(serverUrl);
            AuthenticationResponse? authToken;
            var client = new RestClient(serverUrl);
            var request = new RestRequest(Endpoints.OAuthToken(serverUrl), Method.Post);
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", $"username={userName}&password={password}&grant_type=password&" +
                                $"client_id={clientId}&client_secret={clientSecret}&scope={scope.ToString().ToLower()}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                authToken = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AuthenticationResponse>(response.Content);
                session.Authenticated = true;
                session.AuthToken = authToken.XAuthToken;
                session.RefreshToken = authToken.RefreshToken;
                request = new RestRequest(Endpoints.ApiInfo(session), Method.Get);
                request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                request.AddHeader("X-Auth-Token", session.AuthToken);
                response = client.Execute(request);
                var apiInfoResponse = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<APIResponse>(response.Content);
                session.CustomerId = apiInfoResponse.data.user.customer_id;
                session.BaseUrl = apiInfoResponse.data.versions[0].url;
                Log.Information("Authentication Succeeded");
```

Is this possbile or the two log file approach is the correct one?

Thanks
Sorry once again for any misconduct... I'm starting.

Pedro

Trying to use serilog with just one object and resulting in only one log file